# Image Transform Internal Server Error (500 code) after Craft CMS update

Tags: image-transforms, error, manual-updates

I just updated an "older" Craft site (version 2.4.2702) to the newest update (version 2.6.2958).

But now all my image thumbnails in the back-end are missing and if I upload any new assets, the thumbnail is not generated and I get a Internal Server Error 500 on the front-end as the URL it points to is still the `cpresources/transforms/283?x=qFc4lFWR5` kind of URL.

The image thumbnail itself is also not generated anymore in the folder it is supposed to go in. I didn't change any folder permissions (only updated the new app folder ofcourse with the correct permissions). I'm able to upload assets so the permissions should be fine I guess.

I've had issues like this before, but those were resolved, so I don't know what is causing this issue again. Is there anything I forgot about this update that I needed to change? I needed to do a manual update.

The logs I get are these:

```
2017-01-17 10:13:26

Level   info
Category    application
Message [Forced] Finished task 14 (GeneratePendingTransforms).
2017-01-17 10:13:26

Level   info
Category    application
Message [Forced] Starting task GeneratePendingTransforms that has a total of 0 steps.
```

**UPDATE**

I do get a PhP error:

```
[18-Jan-2017 14:04:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Imagine\Imagick\Imagick::getImageAlphaChannel() in MY-BASE-PATH-HERE/craft/app/vendor/pixelandtonic/imagine/lib/Imagine/Imagick/Imagick.php on line 191
```

But through the PhPInfo in the Craft CP I can see that Imagick extension 2.2.2 is installed with ImageMagick 6.7.2-7, so according to this page the method should exist: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagealphachannel.php.

**UPDATE 2**

As I dumbly clicked "rebuild all asset indexes" on the live site (instead of on the local development site in the browser tab next to it *aaargh*) I quickly added `'imageDriver' => 'gd',` to the config as a workaround.

Comment: If you're not seeing any errors in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`, then it must be your web server that is generating the 500 internal server errors.  Try checking your web server's error logs.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the server error logs. I did see a log in the access log files. And there was code 500 together with code 261 that after some searching has something to do with write permissions. But all my asset folders have write permissions (even 777).

Comment: My bad, I had devmode on false on the live server. Sorry for that. Edited my post with the PhP error. I'm looking further into it!

Comment: The Imagick changelogs are pretty sketchy, I've found.  Hard to find out what changed between versions. Even resorted to digging through the C source code several times just to figure it out.  But I'd guess if you updated your Imagick extension and ImageMagick library to the latest stable versions, it'd work.

Comment: Anyway, would you mind posting your workaround as an answer for now?

Answer (score 1):

More a workaround than a solution but I added

> 'imageDriver' => 'gd'

to the config so it didn't use Imagick anymore. Works as supposed to now.

Comment: ar there any advantages from magick to gd?

Comment: What I have read in the documents of craft CMS not so much I think. This is what they say: Adds animated GIF support to Craft, and preserves 8-bit and 24-bit PNGs when creating image transforms, rather than converting them to 32-bit.